# use GPIO sysfs in Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.14.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, gpio

I am trying to get a viperboard USB GPIO board running on ubuntu.
I already got a newer kernel, because I understood that the 3.13 kernel doesn't support the viperboard so well.

What I want to do is to use the /sys/class/gpio sysfs interface for GPIO so I can develop raspberry pi projects on my PC and then use them
on my RPi.

My Problem - the /sys/class/gpio directory is missing.
The config of the kernel shows:

> CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS is not set

Does this mean I have to compile a new kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to recompile the kernel with CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS set; now I see the /sys/class/gpio directory. Ubuntu does not enable gpio sysfs by default.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Ubuntu-GPIO problems with the [pigpio library](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/).

> It runs a daemon started with sudo, which is controlling the GPIO pins. A client program (started without sudo) communicates with the deamon and thus indirectly controls the pins.
>
> You can even run the client on a remote machine. This way a ROS node can control the GPIO pins of a remote raspberry, which itself isn't even running ROS.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36031858/3419103) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/223601/importerror-no-module-named-rospy/?answer=223671#post-id-223671) post for reference.