# Access GPIO pins of Raspberry Pi 2 with ROS

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, gpio, ros, sysfs

I'm trying to access the GPIO pins of a Raspberry Pi 2 using the robot operating systen ROS. I know, there are many tutorials on this topic. But my problem is as follows:

- The recommended Linux distribution for ROS is **Ubuntu**. Since there are other Ubuntu machines in the ROS network, I'd like to avoid compiling ROS for a different OS.
- In Ubuntu the **`/sys/class/gpio`** sysfs is not enabled by default. I'd need to recompile the kernel with a [custom configuration](http://elinux.org/GPIO#Configure_the_kernel_for_GPIO_support_in_sysfs).
- If I can't use `/sys/class/gpio`, it looks like I need to use **`/dev/mem`** (e.g. with the [RPi.GPIO](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) package).
- But `/dev/mem` is only accessible to **root**.
- And I can't run a ROS node as root, since it's missing **`rospy`** and the whole ROS setup.

**So, what's the "easiest" way to get GPIO access within a ROS node?**

Comment: You have a kernel that's not fit for the purpose you need, use one that is. Don't start trying to do hacky stuff with /dev/mem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a rather clean solution to my problem:

The [**pigpio library**](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) is what I needed. It runs a daemon started with sudo, which is controlling the GPIO pins. A client program (started without sudo) communicates with the deamon and thus indirectly controls the pins.

You can even run the client on a remote machine. This way a ROS node can control the GPIO pins of a remote raspberry, which itself isn't even running ROS.

My current setup is a rospy node (indigo) on a fitlet PC talking to a Raspberry Pi 2, both running Ubuntu 14.04.

[djsw's answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/223601/importerror-no-module-named-rospy/?answer=223671#post-id-223671) in the ROS forum pointed me in the right direction.